# Why can I assign an int literal to double, but not to Double?

Tags: java

Why can I assign an int literal to double, but not to Double? What is the concept here? I am not able to understand, when I use `double` without decimal point number, it shows no error, but when I use `Double` without decimal point number, it shows error.

For example:

1. `double d = 458; // not showing any error.`
2. `Double d1 = 459; // shows error. Says "required double, provided int"`

Comment: Double is object and double is primitive. Double works as a constructor and it expects double value. by default 459 is int, if you want to pass it as double use 459d

Comment: `459` is treated as a primitive `int` and it can't be *boxed* into `Double`. There's no issuer issues with first line because compiler performs *widening*  and `int` value `459` is being promoted into `double`. The key point is that compiler does either *boxing* or *widening* but **not both**.

Comment: The "concept" is only a limited set of conversion sequences are possible ... per the JLS.  The restrictions are to avoid problems with ambiguity; i.e. when there are two or more allowed sequences that could produce different results.   The duplink quotes the relevant section of the JLS for you to read.